# jQuery livesearch not working when loading asynchronously

Tags: jquery, livesearch

I have a livesearch and it uses an unordered list, like this:

```
<input id="search"/>
<ul id="list>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
</ul>
```

Now I have the liveSearch function put on these items:

```
$('#search').liveUpdate('#list').focus();
```

At first I was testing with a static list, it worked like charm.
Now I'm trying to load it asynchronous with the following statements:

```
//$('#list').load('/search/organization');
//$('#list').load('/search/person');
//$('#list').load('/search/debitor');
$('#list').load('/search/accountname');
```

The data is loaded as normal but now the search isn't working anymore. I'm not that used to using ajax so maybe this is a common problem?

Thanks in advance,

EDIT:

When I add this line of code, or alert it somewhere else it returns 1. There is always only one element in the ul.

```
$('#list').load('/search/organization');
var test = jQuery('#list');
alert(test.length);
```

Still no sollution found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin actually has a cache of the `<li>` elements that are being replaced, so you need to "unbind" the former handler and re-bind it again, like this:

```
$('#list').load('/search/accountname', function() {
  $('#search').unbind('keyup').liveUpdate('#list');
});
```

Since [the plugin](http://ejohn.org/blog/jquery-livesearch/) is rigged up to the [`.keyup()`](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) handler, you're just unbinding that and adding a new one.  To *really* clean up, you could add a `.parents('form').unbind('submit')`, but if you had any *other* submit handlers on the `<form>`, that'd be a bad idea :)

Comment: Thanks, but i'm getting a liveUpdate is not a function error.

Variations aren't working either.

Comment: @baklap - Are you by chance including jQuery again in the page, or in the loaded page? that'll wipe out any plugins when it happens.

Comment: @NickCraver - No I put it on the end of the .js loading queue.

I do have to add:
$('#search').liveUpdate('#list').focus();
on the end to rebind it, isn't it?

Still not working though.

Comment: @baklap - Nope....if you're getting `is not a function` then the plugin's getting erased...if you have a link I can take a quick look.

Comment: Would like but it runs locally on a development server.
Maybe it's because the liveUpdate is bound after the loading. Let me have a look.

edit: nup, still the same error

Comment: @baklap - What result do you get when you type `$.fn.liveUpdate` in the console?

Comment: @NickCraver >>> $.fn.liveUpdate();
TypeError: $.fn.liveUpdate is not a function { message="$.fn.liveUpdate is not a function", more...}

Very very strange...

Comment: Hmm ghmm blegh, I think I found it.

Im making use of the Zend Framework with ZFDebug included. The error occurs with ZFDebug. Man what a waste of time.

Comment: Hmm it doens't output the error anymore. It aint working either.

Comment: @baklap - Can you elaborate, or have a page you can provide a link to?

Comment: @Nick Craver. I;VE GOT IT! Finally.

I was loading an <ul> in another <ul> instead of a <li>.

Stupid small problem in combination with a conflict with ZFDebug. Hmm thanks for your help!